# iterate over cells in dataframe and search for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with some missing values. I want to iterate over each cell and change the value, if the cell is not empty:

```
    rows = len(df.index)
    columns = len(df.columns)
    matches = ['some string1', 'some string2']

    for x in range(0, rows):
        if (matches[0] in df.iloc[x, 12]) and (df.isnull().any(axis=1)):
            df.iloc[x, 12] = "Something"

    #The code above gives me this error:

__nonzero__
raise ValueError(ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Second try and another Error:

```
if (matches[0] in df.iloc[x, 12]) and (df.iloc[x, 12] != ""):

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Third try and another error:

```
if (matches[0] in df.iloc[x, 12]) and (pd.notnull(x)):

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

I tried more but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

for the first try change and to & will fix the error:

```
if (matches[0] in df.iloc[x, 12]) & (df.isnull().any(axis=1)):
```

And generally when you check if something is null(None) do it first in the order of the conditions:

```
if (pd.notnull(x) & (matches[0] in df.iloc[x, 12])):
```

Comment: I changed it but became the same error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

Comment: For your second solution became this error: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. I don't know whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

Returns a `pandas.Series` of `True` and `False` values, so placing it in an `if` statement means you're trying to evaluate a series of these values.

You might want to only evaluate the row in question:

```
df.iloc[x].isnull().any()
```

or

```
df.isnull().any(axis = 1).iloc[x]
```

However it would be easier to perform it on the whole DataFrame using conditional indexing instead of iterating over each row:

```
df.iloc[(df.iloc[:,12].str.contains(matches[0])) & (df.isnull().any(axis = 1)), 12] = 'Something'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I became the same error:  argument of type 'float' is not iterable.

Comment: And the last solution gives me: NotImplementedError:  iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Comment: @shimaamini can I ask you to check your pandas version? You can do this with `pd.__version__`

Comment: @shimaamini it also sounds like your `matches` object is overwritten somewhere in your code that is not shown here.

Comment: Pandas Version is : 1.3.2. I checked it, there is no any other "machtes" in my code.